# No hierarchical submenus shown in MATE?

Tags: mate-desktop, menu, menu-editor

The menu editor named mozo allows me to make submenus. But the actual menu shows without submenus and all items inside submenus are shown under the top level menu.

In short: the whole menu structure is flattened into top level menu + all items underneath.

How do I display the menu with all submenus, exactly as in the editor? (which you simply can invoke by right clicking on "Menu" followed by "Edit menu".)

Distro: Pop OS with MATE.
Note: I think this is a MATE issue and has nothing to do with the Linux distro.